# How to take care of ridiculousness?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, quality-evaluation

Ok so we have a sunni moderator, he finds the logic of a Shia poster ridiculous. For example  in my [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/was-hazrat-ali-ra-born-inside-the-kabba-with-the-walls-cracked/12464?noredirect=1#12464), the [accepted] answer says, the crack in Kabba wall was because of birth of Ali (RA). The Sunni moderator thinks 'What a ridiculous answer' and hence delete it. For Shia Muslim on the other hand, 'It makes perfect sense'. Remember this is religious we are talking about. Things that make perfect sense to you as Sunni may be totally ridiculous to an Atheist for example.

When I asked this question, I was **not** looking of scientific evidence. I know this site does not adhere to Scientific rules but religious dogma and belief. My point was, I heard this from a fellow friend and I just want to confirm, if this is the belief by Shia Muslims. I got the answer, the answer got +5 votes that was enough for me that yes this is the belief of our Shia brothers so I accepted the answer. I know that the answer may not be best quality but it sufficed me. Mark Gravel pointed some useful comment at the bottom of the answer as well.

My question is, it is moderator duty to clean the **ridiculousness** in the answers or leave it as it? After all this is religious site and by leaving people believes/views as it is, we know better about them and we can make a more informed decision if someone want to change faith etc. What is your view on this? My view is, leave it as it is if it got +votes. The more votes it got that means that is more accepted belief. On the other hand, if a answer contains *ridiculousness* and has no votes or even down votes, it *may* be deleted. But even in that case, the moderator must point to poster, if he has any ground on what he says and give a friendly message that he needs to backup his statement with some proof.

---

1. The reason I asking this, the accept answer in my question was deleted below [It was undeleted by another moderator today].

[image]
2. There is this [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/934/why-shia-muslims-use-a-stone-for-saying-prayers-but-sunni-muslims-dont/938#938) which has +26 vote but was deleted for plagiarism, although it has +26 votes and quite a bit of material from the poster himself.

[image]

Comment: Deleting plagiarism isn't because of "ridiculousness", it's because of site policy and general professional standards.

Comment: is there any tool available to you that marks the answer as low quality that needs improvement. I have seen it in some question, not on this site though. One can use that instead I guess rather than deleting it altogether.

Comment: relevant meta discussion: [What should be the grace period before a post which doesn't provide the required attribution is deleted?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/932/22)

Comment: @muslim1 it seems you are new here... 26 upvotes doesn't mean the answer has good contents. Users are upvoting answers just because they agree with it. Hence, saying (26 upvotes == Good) is wrong. One more thing, The user that has 26 upvotes for the 2nd time after warning him and then improving his answer by a another user. Comes back and post the previuos plagarized material which doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Something with 26 upvotes is probably very good. But if it's plagiarized, it deserves to be deleted or needs to cite its references.